# How to get the mouse position relative to the window viewport in javascript?

Tags: javascript, height, dom-events, viewport

`event.pageY` gets the mouse position relative to the entire document height (`document.documentElement.offsetHeight` I assume).

But how do I get the mouse position relative to the current viewport, which is `document.documentElement.clientHeight`?

For example, if the browser window size has a 720 pixel height, I scroll down 3 pages and keep the mouse in the middle of the window, the position should be "360", not 1800 (720 x 3 - 720 / 2).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try using `event.clientY` that should always return the correct value regardless of scrolling

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.clientY

Comment: This doesn't seem to be relative to the webpage though. I think this is relative to the client's monitor. So if the browser was only taking up the right half of the screen, and someone clicked in the top left corner of the webpage, it would return something different than if the browser was full screen, and someone clicked in the same position.

Comment: The question specifically says _viewport_, which is _exactly_ what the answer implies. I don't understand why the "this doesn't seem to be relative to the webpage though" comment is upvoted? I mean sure, yeah -- `clientY` isn't "relative to webpage", did anyone ask for that? Also, `clientY` is _not_ (despite what the commenter _thought_, by his own admission) relative to "client's monitor" -- `screenX` and `screenY` properties do that. Regardless, the answer is accepted for the right reasons here.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`event.clientY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.clientY) to get the [mouse position](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#position) relative to the browser viewport ([Compatibility table](http://quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#mousepos)).

Answer (score 7):

Horizontal mouse position **relative to viewport**:

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
    console.log(event.clientY) // THIS should do what you want     
})
```

---

The **complete list of options** are:

- **e.clientY/Y**: position relative to **viewport**
- **e.screenX/Y**: position relative to **screen**
- **e.pageX/Y**: position relative to **page** (different from viewport if the page is scrolled)

---

Run the snippet below to **see the different positions updated in real time**:

```js
const updateView = (e = {}) =>  document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = `
  <div>
    Relative to screen:<br>
    e.screenX: <b>${e.screenX || '0'}</b><br>
    e.screenY: <b>${e.screenY || '0'}</b>
  </div>
  <div>
    Relative to viewport:<br>
    e.clientX: <b>${e.clientX || '0'}</b><br>
    e.clientY: <b>${e.clientY || '0'}</b>
  </div> 
  <div>
    Relative to page (scroll to see the difference with viewport):<br>
    e.pageX: <b>${e.pageX || '0'}</b><br>
    e.pageY: <b>${e.pageY || '0'}</b>
  </div>
`

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = `BIG CONTENT `.repeat(300)

document.addEventListener('mousemove', updateView)

updateView()
```

```css
#log { display:flex;justify-content:center;position:fixed }
#log > div { flex: 1 1 0 }
```

```html
<div id='log'></div>
<div id='content' style='opacity:.1'></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was in similar situation, I required cursor's coordinates w.r.t the Viewport (since my page was scrollable).

I tried other answers here, they didn't seem to work once the screen was scrolled (they worked well with non-scrollable pages).

Upon reading a few documentation page of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent
I found that while working with scrollable page, if you need X and Y coordinates w.r.t the current Viewport (i.e. even if scrolled), it would be better to use
`event.pageX` instead.

`var pageX = MouseEvent.pageX;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX

Comment: That's not relative to the "viewport", that's relative to the entire "document".

Answer (score 1):

If you want the viewport coords, not the screen, client, or page coords, this is the answer...

```
const eleSvg = document.querySelector('svg');
let point = eleSvg.createSVGPoint();
var cursorpt =  point.matrixTransform(eleSvg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
point.viewport_x =  cursorpt.x
point.viewport_y =  cursorpt.y
```